# What is the difference between quantum thermodynamics and nonequilibrium QFT?

Tags: thermodynamics, quantum-field-theory, terminology

I see a lot of books of Nonequilibrium QFT and they study the thermodynamics on quatum realms, but what is the difference about that and Quantum Thermodynamics? They study the same thing only with different approach?

Comment: Hello! Could you please list the books you are referring to?